# How to get the click coordinates relative to SVG element holding the onclick listener?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I haven't been able to calculate the click coordinates (x and y) relative to the element triggering the event. I have not found an easy example online.

I have a simple `svg` (with 100px left margin) in an HTML page. It contains a `group` (translated 30px 30px) which has an `onclick` listener attached. And inside that `group` I have a `rect` with 50px width and height.

After I click any part of the `group` element, I get an event object with coordinates relative to the HTML page (`evt.clientX` and `evt.clientY`).

What I need to know is where exactly the user clicked inside the `group` element (the element holding the onclick listener).

How do I convert `clientX` and `clientY` coordinates to the `group` element coordinates. So say, if I click the top leftmost part of the `rect` it should give me x=0 and y=0.

Here is currently what I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background:black;
            }
            svg{
                fill:white;
                background:white;
                position: absolute;
                top:100px;
                left:100px;
            }
            
        </style>
        <script>
            function clicked(evt){
                alert("x: "+evt.clientX+" y:"+evt.clientY);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200">
                <g transform="translate(30 30)" onclick="clicked(evt)">
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/>
                </g>
            </svg>      
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to use `getBoundingClientRect()`: http://jsfiddle.net/fLo4uatw/

```
function clicked(evt){
    var e = evt.target;
    var dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = evt.clientX - dim.left;
    var y = evt.clientY - dim.top;
    alert("x: "+x+" y:"+y);
}
```

Comment: Note that this script doesn't work if your viewBox is different from the default (`viewBox="0 0 width height"`). I've posted an alternative answer, which works with any viewBox.

Answer (score 105):

Tolokoban's solution has the limitation that it doesn't work if your viewBox deviates from the default, that is if it is different from `viewBox="0 0 width height"`. A better solution that also takes viewBox into account is this:

```
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();  // Created once for document

function alert_coords(evt) {
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;

    // The cursor point, translated into svg coordinates
    var cursorpt =  pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    console.log("(" + cursorpt.x + ", " + cursorpt.y + ")");
}
```

(Credit goes to Smerk, who [posted the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752519/svg-capturing-mouse-coordinates))

If the viewBox is not set or set to the default, this script will return the same values as Tolokoban's script. But if you have an SVG like `<svg width="100px" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 200">`, only this version will give you the correct results.

Comment: What Alexander sayd is perfectly right! My solution was specific to the posted example where thee is a default viewPort.

Comment: note thet `svg` is a reference to the svg element. If using react, you can get the reference by adding a `ref={(ref) => this.svg = ref}` prop.

Comment: As far as I can see, it is supported by all browsers that support SVG. According to [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff972165(v=vs.60)), the method `SVGSVGElement.createSVGPoint()` has been supported since IE9, which is also when SVG support started in general. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement#Browser_compatibility) provides a support table for `SVGSVGElement`, and as `createSVGPoint()` is not listed as a separate feature, I assume that it falls under "basic support" - meaning that it is supported by all browsers that support SVG.

Comment: My statement about browser support may be wrong. `getScreenCTM()` is a method of `SVGGraphicsElement`, which according to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement) is not supported by IE, although [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh535760(v=vs.85)) mentions it on their website. Just test with the earliest version of each browser that supports SVG to make sure.

Comment: This works for the first click and in later click it doesnt work

Comment: With the deprecation of SVGPoint, this answer should probably be updated to use DOMPoint instead. It works the same, but can be constructed using `new DOMPoint(x, y)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

The proposed solutions are great, but they won't work in all scenarios.

The OP's post is titled

> How to get the click coordinates relative to SVG element **holding the
> onclick listener**?

So if you put the onclick listener onto your root `svg` element, whenever you click on any of its child elements, `getBoundingClientRect` will give you the child's `Rect` and you won't get the click coordinates relative to the root `svg`.

This was my case as I needed the coordinates relative to the root at all times, and the solution that worked for me was to use `e.target.farthestViewportElement`. Here's an excerpt from my (JSX) code:

```
const onClickSvg = e => {
  const { farthestViewportElement: svgRoot } = e.target;
  const dim = svgRoot.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.clientX - dim.left;
  const y = e.clientY - dim.top;
  console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`);
};

<svg onClick={onClickSvg}>...</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

createSVGPoint is deprecated according to Mozilla.  Use static method of DOMPoint.fromPoint(svg_element);

```
function dom_track_click(evt) {
    //<svg   onclick='dom_track_click(event); >
    let pt = DOMPoint.fromPoint(document.getElementById('svg_canvas')); 
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;

    // The cursor point, translated into svg coordinates
    let cursorpt =  pt.matrixTransform(document.getElementById('svg_canvas').getScreenCTM().inverse());
    console.log("(" + cursorpt.x + ", " + (cursorpt.y) + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding notes after many researchs (and fails!).

For a **css translated svg**, to get the coordinates of a clicked point for drawing.

In my case, using a mouse wheel event to translateX, so the actual rendering depends of the screen size and of the actual translated value.

I recommend for your use case to make a little drawing like the following, it will help a lot for figuring out what's going on.

[image: Svg translateX click point]

Let's say my svg has for id: `shoke`
To get the total computed width, in pixels:

```
shoke.getBoundingClientRect()["width"]
```

Need to know the actual translateX value. (From the right, so it is a negative number, on this case)

```
shoke.style.transform.substr(11).slice(0,-3)
```

Note that it return a string and not an integer, so:

```
+shoke.style.transform.substr(11).slice(0,-3)
```

Now to get the coordinates of the mouse, **related to the pixel x0 of the screen**.

```
let pt = document.querySelector('svg').createSVGPoint();
pt.matrixTransform(shoke.getScreenCTM().inverse())["x"]
```

So, at the end, to obtain the precise **x** point:

```
svg_width - (svg_width + translated) + from_pixel x0 of the screen_click
```

Is something like this:

```
shoke.getBoundingClientRect()["width"]  - (shoke.getBoundingClientRect()["width"] + +shoke.style.transform.substr(11).slice(0,-3)) + pt.matrixTransform(shoke.getScreenCTM().inverse())["x"]
```