# How can I get an element position in Snap.svg API?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I use Snap.svg API. I need to get an element position:

```
const outPort = paper.select(`#${outPortId}`);
console.log(`outPort: {x:${outPort.attr("x")},y:${outPort.attr("y")}}`);
```

Console output:

> outPort: {x:null,y:null}

How can I get an element position in Snap.svg API?

Comment: `.getBBox()` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Dimity's suggestion helped me; using

```
outPort.getBBox().cx, outPort.getBBox().cy
```

Also, converting these coordinates to client window coordinates like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42711775/969483), was useful.