# Blazor - Add element to SVG object

Tags: svg, blazor-client-side

I want to manipulate an SVG object with blazor, is it possible to do this via C# client side, or do I need to use javascript.
For example, draw a line programatically based on clicks in the SVG area.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I found a lot on adding SVG component, but nothing on adding elements to the already existing svg component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SVG file contents as the markup in a Blazor component, and then do any of the Blazor-y things you'd normally do.

Put a variable in the svg markup, and build it as a string.

Here's a highly-simplified excerpt:
(MySvgComponent.blazor)

```
<svg blah blah blah>
    <polyline fill="none" stroke="#0074d9"
        stroke-width="2" points="@PointString" />
</svg>
@code {
    public string @PointString {get;set;}
    public void AddPoint (int X, int Y){
         @PointString += " " + X + "," + Y;
}
```

You'll have to add your own code to figure out where you want to add the points.  You could make a List<Point> parameter to pass in from a parent or something, and then call AddPoint in a foreach loop in OnInitialized().  You could also very easily replace the stroke color or anything else by replacing literals like "0074d9" with variables "@myColorString."

Handling mouse-click locations will require some fancy JS work.  Try using Javascript Interop with something like the following:
[How to get the click coordinates relative to SVG element holding the onclick listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261304/how-to-get-the-click-coordinates-relative-to-svg-element-holding-the-onclick-lis)