# Cannot get offset from rect

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I need to get the rect's offset so I can access the mouse position on the rect, but what I'm getting is the svg's offset.

```
 <svg width="500" height="100" style="border: 1px solid black">
      <rect  x="50" fill="#ccc" width="100" height="100" ></rect>
  </svg>
```

```
<script>
      const rect = document.querySelector('svg rect')
      rect.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=>{
              console.log(event.offsetX)
         })
</script>
```

when I hover the mouse cursor on the rect's left, I should get -1

Comment: What happens if you add an id to the rect and target the id with the selector?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez, Same behavior, the difference that i will get using id.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you only get the **mouse/cursor coordinates.**

So you need to calculate the distance between cursor x/y and the left x of your `<rect>` element:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const rect = document.querySelector('svg rect');
// get rect coordinates/boundaries
const bb = rect.getBBox();
const {x,y,width, height} = bb;

rect.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=>{
  let pt = mouseToSvgCoords(svg, event);
  let rectOffset = pt.x - x;
  offset.textContent = rectOffset;
  console.log(rectOffset)
})

function mouseToSvgCoords(svg, e){
    // get svg user space coordinates
    let point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = e.clientX;
    point.y = e.clientY;
    let ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
    point = point.matrixTransform(ctm);
    return point;
}
```

```html
 
 <svg width="500" height="100" style="border: 1px solid black">
      <rect  x="50" fill="#ccc" width="100" height="100" ></rect>
  </svg>
  
   <p id="offset"></p>
```

Optional: translate screen coordinates to SVG user units as explained [here:"How to get the click coordinates relative to SVG element holding the onclick listener?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261304/how-to-get-the-click-coordinates-relative-to-svg-element-holding-the-onclick-lis#42711775)

```
function mouseToSvgCoords(svg, e){
    // get svg user space coordinates
    let point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = e.clientX;
    point.y = e.clientY;
    let ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
    point = point.matrixTransform(ctm);
    return point;
}
```

You can skip this step if the SVG coordinates are equal to screen coordinates .